# Applescript/Excel I want to lose the decimal answer

Tags: excel, formatting, applescript

I'm writing an applescript to deal with a spreadsheet for XML, and it's almost finished, but I'm finding that whenever it retrieves the value from a cell, and that value is a number, it formats it with a decimal.

4 becomes 4.0

How can I force it to get only the whole number? Numbers are not the only value it will ever get.

Here's the relevant code:

```
-- Copy field from SS
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        goto reference cellNum
        set GotValue to value of active cell as string
        delay 0.3
        --tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 2
    end tell
```

And I know I could process it through a function that delimits and keeps only the first part before the decimal, but like I said, more things than numbers go through this, paragraphs can too. So that wouldn't be good.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking on, this was solved by making a function to check if the input is a Real, and if it is, converting it to an integer and then a string. Like this:

```
on isReal(x)
    return ({class of x} is in {real})
end isReal

if isReal(GotValue) then
        set GotValue to GotValue as integer
    end if
    set GotValue to GotValue as string
```